# Consuming a secure service with x509 certificate using JAX-WS

Tags: jax-ws, ws-security, java-metro-framework

I need to consume  a secure web service with this policy:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="test_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Lax/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
            <sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:X509Token
                            sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:X509Token>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens>
            <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Wss10>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Using AXIS2 framework I can doit without problem but with JAX-WS always my securityheader is blank.

Any help or a tutorial to do this?

UPDATE:

I managed to load the WSIT and this config [1] but with this error now [2]

[1]

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="my_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Lax/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
            <sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:X509Token>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens>
            <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Wss10>
            <sc1:KeyStore wspp:visibility="private" alias="importkey" keypass="importkey" storepass="importkey" type="JKS" location="${keystore.dir}/pac.jks"/>
            <sc1:TrustStore wspp:visibility="private" peeralias="importkey" storepass="importkey" type="JKS" location="${keystore.dir}/pac.jks"/>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

[2]

```
Información: WSP5018: se ha cargado la configuración de WSIT desde el archivo: file:client_Autentica/target/classes/wsit-client.xml.
mar 24, 2014 1:10:49 PM com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler getKeyStore
Grave: WSS1540: no se ha encontrado el elemento KeyStore. Compruebe la afirmación de KeyStore en la configuración de WSIT
mar 24, 2014 1:10:49 PM com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl getDefaultPrivKeyCertRequest
Grave: WSS0216: Se ha producido un error al utilizar CallbackHandler para: SignatureKeyCallback.DefaultPrivKeyCertRequest
mar 24, 2014 1:10:49 PM com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl getDefaultPrivKeyCertRequest
Grave: WSS0217: se ha producido un error al utilizar el método CallbackHandler handle().
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: Could not locate KeyStore, check keystore assertion in WSIT configuration
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.getKeyStore(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:2279)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.getDefaultPrivKeyCert(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:1414)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.handle(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:553)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.getDefaultPrivKeyCertRequest(DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.java:261)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.process(SignatureFilter.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processWSSPolicy(HarnessUtil.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processDeep(HarnessUtil.java:278)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.processMessagePolicy(SecurityAnnotator.java:194)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.secureMessage(SecurityAnnotator.java:155)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:388)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:464)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
    at $Proxy40.autentica(Unknown Source)
    at client.WSClient.main(WSClient.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

mar 24, 2014 1:10:49 PM com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter process
Grave: WSS1417: error al procesar la firma [Ljava.lang.Object;@2f186df7
mar 24, 2014 1:10:49 PM com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase secureOutboundMessage
Grave: WSSTUBE0024: error al proteger el mensaje saliente.
com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: Could not locate KeyStore, check keystore assertion in WSIT configuration
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.process(SignatureFilter.java:321)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processWSSPolicy(HarnessUtil.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processDeep(HarnessUtil.java:278)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.processMessagePolicy(SecurityAnnotator.java:194)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.secureMessage(SecurityAnnotator.java:155)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:388)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:464)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
    at $Proxy40.autentica(Unknown Source)
    at client.WSClient.main(WSClient.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: Could not locate KeyStore, check keystore assertion in WSIT configuration
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.getDefaultPrivKeyCertRequest(DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.process(SignatureFilter.java:235)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: Could not locate KeyStore, check keystore assertion in WSIT configuration
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.getKeyStore(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:2279)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.getDefaultPrivKeyCert(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:1414)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.handle(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:553)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.getDefaultPrivKeyCertRequest(DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.java:261)
    ... 24 more

mar 24, 2014 1:10:49 PM com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube processClientRequestPacket
Grave: WSSTUBE0024: error al proteger el mensaje saliente.
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Invalid Security Header
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurableSoapMessage.newSOAPFaultException(SecurableSoapMessage.java:349)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:393)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:464)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
    at $Proxy40.autentica(Unknown Source)
    at client.WSClient.main(WSClient.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: WSSTUBE0024: error al proteger el mensaje saliente.
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:464)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
    at $Proxy40.autentica(Unknown Source)
    at client.WSClient.main(WSClient.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Invalid Security Header
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.getSOAPFaultException(SecurityTubeBase.java:715)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Invalid Security Header
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurableSoapMessage.newSOAPFaultException(SecurableSoapMessage.java:349)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:393)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:323)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

1. create a META-INF folder in \src\main\resources\
2. put this files: wsit-client.xml and Autenticacion.xml inside meta-inf with the following inside:

wsit-client.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <definitions 
 xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="mainclientconfig" 
 >
    <import location="Autenticacion.xml" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
</definitions>
```

Autenticacion.xml:
in this file put your WSDL and at the end put this policy:

```
<wsp1:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_IAutenticacionPolicy">
    <wsp1:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp1:All>
            <sc:KeyStore wspp:visibility="private" alias="youralias" keypass="pass1" storepass="pass" type="JKS" location="${keystore.dir}/your_jks.jks"/>
        </wsp1:All>
    </wsp1:ExactlyOne>
</wsp1:Policy>
```

This is all.

Comment: I just wanted to ask: where do I set they ${kestore.dir}?

Answer (score 0):

I have also spent lots of time to find out the solution.
Problem in my case is wsit-client.xml file not read by the tomcat server and send plain request to server.

Solution is

1. Is your `META-INF` folder in `'src/main'` or `'src/'` ?
2. Check your `wsit-client.xml`file is read by server or not.